# How to reference "deployment name" in an ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Can someone show an example of how to reference the 'deployment name' in an arm template?  I'm planning on using it as prefix so I can concatenate it to other resource names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a built-in function:

```
"[deployment().name]"
```

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-deployment#deployment